# How to call an rspec test from inside another rspec test

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

The title says it all.

I'm working on writing a test that combines two other tests. Instead of repeating code, is there a way to call an rspec test from inside another rspec test, or do I have to write the new test long hand?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [shared examples](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/example-groups/shared-examples) or a [shared context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/example-groups/shared-context).

Comment: Not necessarily. Isn't there a way to just call the tests from inside another? Like being able to call a method from inside another method? That's basically what I'm writing, each it...end block is just a method that executes and gives a pass or fail result.

Comment: There's no rspec-provided way to do this. You're intended to use shared examples rather than having tests which depend on other tests.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'll rework the tests.

Comment: If one of those "inner" tests failed, then *all* tests that depend on it would also fail. This makes the "inner" test redundant, so it shouldn't even be a test at all!

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like `shared_context`, or even just a `before` block? What are you trying to do? If you show us some code, I could give more concrete advice.

Answer (score 0):

RSpec is a unit test framework and unit tests are intended to exclusively test the internal functionality of a single component. Dummy values and mocks should be injected through some form of mock-ups for tests that use external components.

Your code and tess probably aren't following the Single Responsibility Principle, nor standards of test-driven development if you have to do this strange implementation to have run RSpec tests. I'd suggest reading Clean Code by Robert Martin or some other book on programming theory, or just wikipedia Test Driven Development and RSpec guidelines.

If you are doing integration testing which is totally necessary, then you should try some other test strategies too.